# How best to store and download resource files on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, download

How best to store and download CSS and other files (resources) on the page? In separate files or in one? 
If the individual files, it is convenient to change them and work with them, and if a single file, it will be only one request to the server.
Which way to go? Which way effective? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Develop your site using separate files, which are convenient to change and work on.

Combine them into a a single CSS and a single JS file at build time to reduce the number of requests on the live site.